# How to show that the germs of smooth functions form an algebra over the reals?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, differential-geometry, commutative-algebra, smooth-manifolds

I am following the book by William M. Boothby, "An Introduction to Differentiable Manifolds and Riemannian Geometry". He mentions the idea of an algebra over the the reals, I looked into it and according to Wikipedia it is a vector space together with a bilinear map, and on the exercises he defines the germs of $C^\infty$ as:

Let $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f,g$ be two $C^\infty$ functions whose domain of definition both contain $a$, then $f \sim g$ if and only if they agree on some open set containing $a$. And defines the *germs* of a $C^\infty$ function as the collection of equivalence classes, then asks to show that this is an algebra over $\mathbb{R}$. What I am struggling to understand is, what would the vector space and the bilinear operation will be in order to show that this collection is indeed an algebra? I tried finding more examples and definitions of algebras online but I could not, any further reading will be also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given two functions $f,g\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ (or functions defined on a manifold $M\to \mathbb R$), there are two natural functions we can form from these two.

1. A linear combination $(c_1f+c_2g)(x) = c_1f(x) + c_2g(x)$ (here $c_1,c_2$ are two real numbers).
2. The product $(f\cdot g)(x) = f(x)\cdot g(x)$.

You can check that if we are inspecting the germs of functions, the vector space structure on the germs of functions comes from taking linear combinations, and the bilinear map is the one given by taking products of germs.